# Plotting and labelling points on a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm using Beamer and I desperately need to have a picture of the following image:
the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+17$, with points R = (-2, -3), -R = (-2, 3), P = (4,9) and Q=(2,5). I'd also like a straight line through R, P and Q. How can i go about drawing this?

Many thanks!

Comment: When I had to create some pictures of elliptic curves, I used Python because for some reason (I can't actually remember now) I was not too happy with what I could come up with using `pgfplots` and friends. But there seem to be good ways to do this using pgf/pstrickst etc., see https://pbelmans.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/howto-draw-algebraic-curves-using-pgftikz/, https://cryptojedi.org/misc/pstricks.shtml and https://amca01.wordpress.com/2008/04/27/mathematical-diagrams/

Answer (score 5):

Implicit functions are the weak side of TeX based plotting. You can either call the big brother `gnuplot`(see pgfplots manual) to save or you can divide the domain of definition and plot separately.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[no marks,samples=200,domain=-2.571281:5,grid=both]
\addplot[blue] {sqrt(x^3+17)};
\addplot[blue] {-sqrt(x^3+17)};
\coordinate[label={90:$R$}] (R) at (axis cs:-2,3);
\coordinate[label={-90:$-R$}] (-R) at (axis cs:-2,-3);
\coordinate[label={90:$P$}] (P) at (axis cs:4,9);
\coordinate[label={90:$Q$}] (Q) at (axis cs:2,5);
\draw (P) -- (Q) -- (-R);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome! thanks! Is it possible to get the line to extend to infinity, though? And possibility the actual coordinates labelled as well as R, P, Q, -R? it's my fault for not specifying that.

Comment: @Luke You can either use `shorten >` or `shorten <` keys or via `calc` library of tikz `\draw ($(P)!-1!(-R)$) -- ($(P)!2!(-R)$);`. I don't know what you mean by `actual coordinates`

Comment: i tried copying and pasting your source code and it wouldn't compile for some reason... By actual coordinates, I mean R to have the label (-2, -3) as well, etc

Comment: You can use the labels to whatever you wish to typeset. Without the actual error I can't guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You could also draw this sort of plot with [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it).  Compile with `mpost` and include the .eps file it produces with `\includegraphics`.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

u = 1.44cm; % horizontal unit
v = 3.2mm;  % vertical unit

% axes
path xx, yy;
xx = (3 left -- 6 right) scaled u;
yy = (14 down -- 14 up) scaled v;

drawarrow xx withcolor .6 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .6 white;

% the curve
path half_curve, full_curve;
root = -(17**1/3);
s = 0.1;
half_curve = (root, 0) for x=root+s step s until 5.4: .. (x, sqrt(17+x**3)) endfor;
full_curve = (reverse half_curve reflectedabout(left,right) & half_curve) xscaled u yscaled v;
draw full_curve withcolor .67 red;

% the points
pair R, P, Q;
R = (-2u,-3v);
P = (4u,9v);
Q = (2u,5v);

% the line through R and P
z1 = whatever[R,P]; x1 = -3u;
z2 = whatever[R,P]; x2 = +6u;
draw z1--z2;

% labels
dotlabel.top(btex $P$ etex, P); label.lrt(btex $(4,9)$ etex, P);
dotlabel.top(btex $Q$ etex, Q); label.lrt(btex $(2,5)$ etex, Q);
fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam shifted R;
label(btex $R$ etex, R+8 up);
label(btex $(-2,-3)$ etex, R+14 down);
dotlabel.ulft(btex $-R$ etex, R reflectedabout(left,right));

endfig;
end.
```