# I wont to draw this plot, how can I draw it?

Tags: plot

I need exactly this curve in LaTeX:

[image: target image displaying desired plot]

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? And what do you want to do? I don't understand the use of 'drove' in this context.

Comment: Please don't vote to close a new user's first question 10 minutes after it is posted and never vote to close without leaving a comment explaining how the post can be improved.

Comment: @cfr Sorry. Won't do so again.

Comment: Thank you. I need to some Latex code like this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/plotting-and-labelling-points-on-a-graph

Comment: There are definitely ways to draw graphs in LaTeX, [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) is the very first thing that comes to mind, but I know little about it. However, don't run before you can walk. If you're really a beginner, why not just use some graphing software and insert the result as a figure. LaTeX's wonderful and it can certainly draw you graphs, but it is first and foremost a document preparation system. That's what it was designed for, it wouldn't be my first instinct to try to use it for everything, specialised software might make the job easier

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch with a curve  closely looking like your curve: it's one of the standard elliptic cubics. I used `pst-plot`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\def\f{sqrt(2.2*x*(x^2-4))}


\begin{document}

\psset{plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve, algebraic, arrowinset=0.12, }%
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.5,-7.5)(5,8)
    \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue3, ticksize=-2pt 2pt, labels =none, arrows=->, ](0,0)(-4.5,-7.5)(5,8)[$x$, -120][$y$, -135]
    %
    \psset{linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=IndianRed3}
    \psplot{-2}{0}{\f}%
    \psplot{2}{5}{\f}%
    \psplot{-2}{0}{-\f}%
    \psplot{2}{5}{-\f}%
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `x²` should most probably be `x^2`.

Comment: @Henri Menke: Yes, I should have checked. My editor saves `^2,\gamma, …` but displays `², γ, …` for a better code readability. Thanks  for pointing it.